# Postfix or sendmail monitoring

Tags: sendmail, postfix-mta

I’m interested in alerting a support team in email when mail is backing up and not being relayed as expected, ie sending is delayed. I tried in nagios, there isn't any solution. I tried with logwatch, it is not the desired one.

The desired solution:
If the mail is not sent "status=sent (250 Ok)", then alert in mail.
It is easy, the problematic part is to avoid the repetition. So once an alert found in case of the second check not sent any alert relates to this.

How can be this done ?

Maybe postfix has an own solution ?

Comment: You might try setting [`delay_warning_time`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#delay_warning_time) to nonzero. Note that you might also need to fiddle with [`notify_classes`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#notify_classes)

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting write-up by an op5 developer [here](http://www.it-slav.net/blogs/2008/11/06/email-delivery/).

This is a different approach, but will allow you to actively test mail sending using the [check_email_delivery plugin](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Email-and-Groupware/check_email_delivery/details).

```
#Gjort av peter@it-slav.net
#/opt/monitor/op5/nagiosgraph/map_custom/email_delivery.map

# Service type: email delivery

#   output: EMAIL DELIVERY OK - 8 seconds, 8 delay

#   perfdata:

/output:.+?(\d+) seconds, (\d+) delay/

and push @s, [ Email_delivery,

               [ "delivery", GAUGE, $1 ],

               [ "delay", GAUGE, $2 ] ];
```

As far as suppression of extra messages goes, I'm more familiar with op5, which allows the suppression of repeated notifications out of the box.

Comment: Hi, thank you, yes I alredy tried this, I mean all the three plugins in this package, but it did't work :(